# jQuery ajax post escapes data automatically? How to decode in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Due to my observations, jQuery.ajax seems to auto-escape objects that are posted to the server. Is that true? I cannot find any documentation about it.

How can I decode the whole object serverside?

Is it correct to json_decode?

More explanation:

JS:

```
var obj;
obj.field1 = "this is a string with it's words";
$.ajax({
   url: 'urlPost',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {data: obj},
```

in PHP:

```
$_POST['data']['obj']['field1']
```

becomes

> this is a string with it\'s words

Comment: [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: sure, I can do that, but is it the right way? Or should I JSONstringify in JS and then json_decode in PHP the object?

Comment: Are you using a version of PHP 5.3 or older and have magic_quotes_gpc turned on? I haven't seen this happen otherwise